# IIS 7 aliases/rewrites between two applications

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have an application that rests on `/app1` and would like all `/app1alias/requests` to alias/rewrite to `/app1/requests`. I have considered creating a [Rewrite Rule](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module), but it results in a 503 Service Unavailable. The [IIS forums](http://forums.iis.net/t/1200342.aspx/1?URL%20rewrite%20rule%20to%20capture%20response%20status%20503%20and%20redirect) suggest that creating a rewrite rule from a page that gives a 503 error will never be attempted rewritten (the hook happens at a later stage).

So I am tempted to think that what I am looking for is some kind of way to alias one name to another. HTTP redirects (rather than server rewrites) are not ideal since they will try to redirect when `app1` keeps referring to `app1alias` and might not preserve POST request data.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lex said in IIS.NET since the request doesn't ever reach IIS you cannot modify\update it in anyway.

However, have you considered setting up a separate virtual directory or application within IIS named (\app1alias) that just points to this location (\app1) ?

Comment: I have considered this, but I am not sure exactly what you mean by "pointing to". As I said, I have excluded HTTP forwarding. I am looking for something equivalent to Apache's Alias directive: I.e., I just want one "web directory" to behave like another.

Comment: basically create a new application in IIS whose physical path points to \app1